# Android - facebook native login throwing ApiException

Tags: android, facebook

I am getting below error when i try to do native login with facebook 3.0 android sdk in my app.
Native login is working for two of my facebook accounts in same device. But when i try to login with thrird account getting exception..
Please help..

> D/KeyguardViewMediator( 2035): setHidden false
>   W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(21961): Exception during service
>   W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(21961):
>   com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: The app must ask for a
>   basic_info permission at install time.
>   W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(21961):   at
>   com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.b(ApiResponseChecker.java:83)
>   W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(21961):   at
>   com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.a(ApiResponseChecker.java:162)
>   W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(21961):   at
>   com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponse.g(ApiResponse.java:158)
>   W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(21961):   at
>   com.facebook.platform.auth.server.AuthorizeAppMethod.a(AuthorizeAppMethod.java:274)
>   W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(21961):   at
>   com.facebook.platform.auth.server.AuthorizeAppMethod.a(AuthorizeAppMethod.java:30)
>   W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(21961):   at
>   com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseHandler.a(ApiResponseHandler.java:55)
>   W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(21961):   at
>   com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseHandler.handleResponse(ApiResponseHandler.java:28)
>   W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(21961):   at
>   com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:325)
>   W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(21961):   at
>   com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:151)
>   W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(21961):   at
>   com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.b(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:103)
>   W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(21961):   at
>   com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:241)
>   W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(21961):   at
>   com.facebook.http.protocol.SingleMethodRunnerImpl.a(SingleMethodRunnerImpl.java:375)
>   W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(21961):   at
>   com.facebook.http.protocol.SingleMethodRunnerImpl.a(SingleMethodRunnerImpl.java:160)
>   W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(21961):   at
>   com.facebook.http.protocol.AbstractSingleMethodRunner.a(AbstractSingleMethodRunner.java:18)
>   W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(21961):   at
>   com.facebook.platform.common.server.SimplePlatformOperation.a(SimplePlatformOperation.java:40)
>   W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(21961):   at
>   com.facebook.platform.common.server.PlatformOperationHandler.a(PlatformOperationHandler.java:59)
>   W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(21961):   at
>   com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.e(BlueServiceQueue.java:302)
>   W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(21961):   at
>   com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.d(BlueServiceQueue.java:54)
>   W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(21961):   at
>   com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue$3.run(BlueServiceQueue.java:232)
>   W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(21961):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:442)
>   W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(21961):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
>   W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(21961):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
>   W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(21961):   at
>   com.facebook.common.executors.ListenableScheduledFutureImpl.run(ListenableScheduledFutureImpl.java:59)
>   W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(21961):   at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
>   W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(21961):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(21961):   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(21961):   at
>   android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
>   W/fb4a(:):GDPDialog(21961): Failed to send
>   W/fb4a(:):GDPDialog(21961):
>   com.facebook.fbservice.service.ServiceException: API_ERROR: API_ERROR
>   W/fb4a(:):GDPDialog(21961):  at
>   com.facebook.fbservice.ops.BlueServiceOperation.c(BlueServiceOperation.java:640)
>   W/fb4a(:):GDPDialog(21961):  at
>   com.facebook.fbservice.ops.BlueServiceOperation.c(BlueServiceOperation.java:48)
>   W/fb4a(:):GDPDialog(21961):  at
>   com.facebook.fbservice.ops.BlueServiceOperation$2.run(BlueServiceOperation.java:605)
>   W/fb4a(:):GDPDialog(21961):  at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
>   W/fb4a(:):GDPDialog(21961):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   W/fb4a(:):GDPDialog(21961):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   W/fb4a(:):GDPDialog(21961):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4856)
>   W/fb4a(:):GDPDialog(21961):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   W/fb4a(:):GDPDialog(21961):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   W/fb4a(:):GDPDialog(21961):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
>   W/fb4a(:):GDPDialog(21961):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
>   W/fb4a(:):GDPDialog(21961):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) W/PowerManagerService(
>   2035): Timer 0x3->0x3|0x0 D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same issue and I fixed this issue in this way. I am directly asking publish permissions without asking read permissions. Because of this reason I am unable to login with facebook. This issue is coming in only one scenario i.e. if we install the facebook app in our mobile and the user is firsttime login with facebook from our app then I am getting this issue and this time we must ask read permissions. If ask publish permissions without asking read permissions then we can't login with facebook and Facebook app will return this error "The app must ask for a basic_info permission at install time."